# enviar Bluetoothsocket a un fragmento en Android

Tags: android, android-studio

Buenas tardes.

En el desarrollo de una app con conectividad bluetooth me ha surgido un pequeño problema, ya que nunca he trabajado con fragments, y los veo algo complicados.

Desde la ventana principal, inicio un fragment nuevo con un boton. Este boton al ser pulsado mandara por bluetooth un caracter. El problema es en como puedo acceder al socket que he creado en la principal para escribir ese caracter.

Desde la principal no tengo problema en hacerlo, envia el caracter, pero al pasar a ese otro fragment, desde su .java, no encuentro manera de acceder al socket, y tampoco me deja mandarlo por paramnetro, ya que me dice que los fragments deben tener un constructor vacio...

GRACIAS!

EDIT:

Codigo main, el cual conecta perfectamente y establece un socket:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,   AsientosFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,ComplementosFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,OpcionesFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

TextView txtlink;
TextView txtnombre1;
TextView txtnombre;
TextView txtestado1;
TextView txtestado;


BluetoothAdapter bAdapter;
UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
BluetoothDevice device;
ThreadConnectBTdevice myThreadConnectBTdevice;
ThreadConnected myThreadConnected;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setTitle("AudioBus Bluetooth Controller");


    txtlink=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtlink);
     txtnombre1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtnombre1);
     txtnombre=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtnombre);
    txtestado1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtestado1);
    txtestado=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtestado);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton)  findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        //    Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
              //      .setAction("Action", null).show();
            finish();
            System.exit(0);

        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


    bAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    device = bAdapter.getRemoteDevice(getIntent().getExtras().getString("MAC"));
    setup();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

public void abrir(View view){
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.audiobus.com"));
startActivity(intent);
 }
 @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    txtestado.setText("");
    txtestado1.setText("");
    txtnombre1.setText("");
    txtnombre.setText("");
    Fragment fragment=null;
    Boolean FragmentoSeleccionado=false;
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.asientos) {
        fragment=new AsientosFragment();
        FragmentoSeleccionado=true;

    } else if (id == R.id.complementos) {
        fragment=new ComplementosFragment();
        FragmentoSeleccionado=true;
    } else if (id == R.id.opciones) {
        fragment=new OpcionesFragment();
        FragmentoSeleccionado=true;
    }

    if (FragmentoSeleccionado) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.Contenedor,fragment).commit();
    }


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

}


public void enviarAsientos(View view) {
    if (myThreadConnected != null) {


        byte[] envio = "Asientos".getBytes();
        myThreadConnected.write(envio);

    }

}

public void enviarComplementos(View view) {
    if (myThreadConnected != null) {


        byte[] envio = "Complementos".getBytes();
        myThreadConnected.write(envio);

    }
}
public void enviarOpciones(View view) {
    if (myThreadConnected != null) {


        byte[] envio = "Opciones".getBytes();
        myThreadConnected.write(envio);

    }
}
public void setup() {

    bAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    txtestado.setText("Conectando...");
    txtnombre.setText(device.getName());
    myThreadConnectBTdevice = new ThreadConnectBTdevice(device);
    myThreadConnectBTdevice.start();

}

private void startThreadConnected(BluetoothSocket socket) {

    myThreadConnected = new ThreadConnected(socket);
    myThreadConnected.start();


}

private class ThreadConnectBTdevice extends Thread{

    BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket=null;
    final BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice;


    private ThreadConnectBTdevice (BluetoothDevice device){
        bluetoothDevice=device;

        try {
            bluetoothSocket=device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
            txtestado.setText("BTSOCKET: "+bluetoothSocket);

        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        boolean succes=false;
        try{

            bluetoothSocket.connect();
            succes=true;
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ");

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    txtestado.setText("Fallo en la conexion...");
                }
            });

            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        if (succes){



            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    txtestado.setText("¡Conectado!");
                }
            });



            startThreadConnected(bluetoothSocket);


        }else{


            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    txtestado.setText("Intente la conexion en otro momento");
                }
            });

        }




    }
}

private class ThreadConnected extends Thread{

    final BluetoothSocket connectedBluetoothSocket;
    final InputStream connectedInputStream;
    final OutputStream connectedOutputStream;

    public ThreadConnected(BluetoothSocket socket){
        connectedBluetoothSocket=socket;
        InputStream in=null;
        OutputStream out=null;


        try{
            in=socket.getInputStream();
            out=socket.getOutputStream();



        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP");

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        connectedInputStream=in;
        connectedOutputStream=out;
    }



    @Override
    public void run() {

        byte[] buffer=new byte[1024];
        int bytes;

        while(true){
            try{
              /*  bytes=connectedInputStream.read(buffer);
                String recibida=new String(buffer,0,bytes);
                System.out.println("RECIBO: "+recibida);
            */
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void write(byte[] buffer){

        try{
            connectedOutputStream.write(buffer);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

}

Fragment desde el que quiero enviar haciendo uso del socket establecido:

```
public class AsientosFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

Button btnup;
Button btndown;
Button btnrear;
Button btnfront;
// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public AsientosFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static AsientosFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    AsientosFragment fragment = new AsientosFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }




}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    System.out.println("AQUIIIIII");
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_asientos,container,false);


    btnup=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnup);
    btndown=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btndown);
    btnrear=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnrear);
    btnfront=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnfront);

     btnup.setOnClickListener(this);
    btndown.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnrear.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnfront.setOnClickListener(this);



    return view;
}

// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }

}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {


    switch (view.getId()){


        case R.id.btnup:
            System.out.println("AAAAAAAAAAAAA");
            break;
        case R.id.btndown:
            System.out.println("BBBBBBBBBBBBBB");

            break;
        case R.id.btnrear:

            break;
        case R.id.btnfront:

            break;


    }

}

public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
```

}

Comment: Te recomiendo que muestres tu código.

Comment: añadido el codigo!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**getActivity()** en el **fragment** te da una referencia a la **activity** que lo contiene.
*Casteando* esta referencia a nuestra MainActivity tenemos acceso a los *atributos* y *métodos* públicos de esta.

Por ejemplo, si en MainActivity existe un método getNivel(), en el fragment podemos poner:

```
MainActivity mainAct = (MainActivity) this.getActivity();
int nivel = mainAct.getNivel();
```

Comment: no puedo, al poner getActivity no me aparece ninguno de los atributos del main ni sus metodos :S

Comment: Es necesario castear el resultado de getActivity() para tener acceso a los métodos. Corregí y completé la respuesta con un ejemplo de un código que me anda bien.

Comment: esto es correcto! mil gracias!!!!